# How to get HTML from precompiled Ember template?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have HTML code that I want to load on certain actions. It's a game and the user is able to switch between scenes. It is not possible to change routes for this, but I have to load HTML code for that scene from a template file.

All templates are precompiled with grunt-ember-templates in one JS file. I can access the according function via `Ember.TEMPLATES["scene_name"]`, but it's a function with a lot of parameters - how can I use this? Or should I use "another way"?

Edit:
The pre-compiled template code like this.

```
Ember.TEMPLATES["scenes/bg1"] = Ember.Handlebars.template(function anonymous(Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
    this.compilerInfo = [4,'>= 1.0.0'];
    helpers = this.merge(helpers, Ember.Handlebars.helpers); data = data || {};

   data.buffer.push("much HTML code");
});
```

All I want is the content of the data Object.

Comment: Why not create a function that returns a specific `Ember.TEMPLATES["scene_name"]`?

Comment: Why not use a partial with a dynamic name like `{{partial sceneName}}`?

Comment: @TheDude how can I do that? This is exactly what I want, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: @DuncanWalker How can I do that with partials?

Comment: Ok, partials does not seem to solve my problem. I need to reload the scene quite a lot of times, and this seems to be not possible with partials.

Comment: If you set the template of the game to just `{{partial sceneName}}` and in your controller have `sceneName` be a dynamically set property depending on the user's progress in the game, it will have the same effect as changing the template of the current view. In other words, it's HTML code loaded on certain actions.

Comment: Ok, that sounds cool - thanks :)